# numpy arrays don't work with python multiprocessing

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to modify a simple array in a simple  `for` loop. Because for my application using a single thread seems to be a bottleneck, I decided to take a look at pythons multiprocessing API. However, it seems I'm unable to concurrently modify a numpy array, even though I'm only modifying each element only once. Take a look at this example code:

import numpy as np
    import multiprocessing

```
arrlen = 3
arr = np.zeros(arrlen)


def func(x):
    arr[x] = 1


for i in range(arrlen):
    func(i)

print(arr)
```

This is all fine and dandy and I get `[1.0, 1.0, 1.0]` as a result just as expected. But as soon as I replace the for loop with `pool.map`, it doesn't work.

```
pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
pool.map(func, range(arrlen))
```

I checked with the PyCharm debugger, func actually gets called with the correct arguments, but the second example prints `[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]`. Any ideas why? Any ideas how I can work around this problem?

Comment: Worker processes don't have access to the master's objects. At most, they get copies, and sometimes not even that. You're operating on copies.

Comment: @user2357112 Would that imply that they have different ids? Because the ids are the same.

Comment: IDs are only meaningful within a process. Objects in different processes may have the same ID.

Comment: Sharing objects across processes is *non trivial*. However, if all you need is a primitive array, you can use https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Array

Comment: I actually need a 2D-Array. Thank you @juanpa.arrivillaga , I'll look into that.

Comment: I mean I could always flatten my array, but it would have been nice if I wouldn't have had to go that route

Comment: Wait. What if I used multi**threading** instead

Answer (score 0):

when using multi processing, each thread you spawn receives processes objects in its own scope.

Your function needs to return a value, and then you need to aggregate those into your global array.

The spawned thread cannot access the global array.
so

```
def func(x):
    return = 1
```

then

```
arr = np.array(pool.map(func, range(arrlen)))
```

would do what you want.